# Redis mass insertion do not work

Tags: python, insert, redis

Problem as simple as I want to do mass insertion in redis using a file and redis-cli in pipe mode. Redis documentation explains this here: http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

My file contains only this command:

```
HMSET client:1 name "Michael"
```

When I try it in my shell (Ubuntu Linux):

```
cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

I get this error:

```
ERR unknown command '$4'
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'echo' command
ERR unknown command '$20'
```

I've seen that other users have same problem ([How to use Redis mass insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195341/how-to-use-redis-mass-insertion)) but I haven't found a good solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

Finally the best option for me was to use a redis client developed in Python. This is a 
pretty straight forward solution, and the point is that we don't need to use/code redis protocol directly.

I choose redis-py client (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py). After installing it you can import its functionality in your python script. This is an example of how my script does the job:

```
import redis

# Connection to 0 database (default in redis)
r = redis.Redis(host="localhost",db=0)

# inserting client hashmaps
r.hmset('client:1', {'name':'John', 'company':'Microsoft'})
r.hmset('client:2', {'name':'James', 'company':'Apple'})

# inserting a list of domains for client 1
r.rpush('client:1:domains','www.microsoft.com','www.msn.com')

#to print values in stdout
print(r.hgetall('client:1'))
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because it contains a solution, and while the question is good, the solution is not. The proposed solution, namely performing a regular sequence of operations, is exactly what the redis docs say is a bad way of doing mass insertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file is supposed to contain Redis protocol, not text commands.

See an example here: [Redis Mass Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870623/redis-mass-insertion/18872283#18872283)

Redis protocol is described here:
http://redis.io/topics/protocol